# Scrollbars won't render in Safari

Tags: css

I've got shadow scrollable elements whose scrolling is linked to the scroll offsets of other elements: https://henrybuilt.github.io/react-sticky-table/

For some reason, I can't get them to appear in Safari on OSX when scrollbars are set to always show. Modifying the z-index after page-load using the dev controls appears to affect them, but not consistently. The scrollbars render just fine in other browsers.

What is causing this rendering issue and how can I fix it?